# GTK3-lib windows are empty in Ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu-12.04, gtk3

I want to compile and run examples of how to use the GTK3 library for my C-programs, but when I run them they only consist of a blank empty space (no buttons or text).

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with GTK-3.0

Some examples I tried to compile and run are these: http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk-getting-started.html

GCC output no errors or warnings with flag `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
also no warnings when running the binary.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Problem is kind of solved.

I formatted my Ubuntu drive and installed a fresh version 12.10 - this didn't change anything!
What fixed my problem was to install GTK 2.0 too, even though I used GTK3 flags to compile and the tutorial mentioned in original post is meant for GTK3.

I'm going to report it as a bug, if no one has an explanation.